# flex app and title missing in browser

Tags: apache-flex

does anyone know why my title isint displaying in browser when i embed a flex object? When the page is loading it shows the title but then when its fully loaded it goes again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit might be the [`IBrowserManager`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/managers/IBrowserManager.html). Are you using it? And if you are, are you calling its [`init()`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/managers/IBrowserManager.html#init()) method with a null value for the `title` argument when your application initializes?